# Is it possible to get different Ghosts?

Tags: destiny

In Destiny, if you go to press the screen where you can equip different Jumpships and Sparrows, your Ghost appears as an 'inventory item' called 'Generalist Shell'.

Is it possible to obtain alternative 'shells', and if so how, and what do they do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [DataMining](http://db.destinytracker.com/inventory/buckets/4023194814), there are a handful of shells in the game, whether or not we can use them all remains to be seen.

That being said, the one confirmed and ingame extra shell for now is the [Frontier Shell](http://www.destinythegame.com/wheretobuy/editions), which came with the special editions of the game.

Shells are purely cosmetic, like ships.

Comment: The Frontier Shell is not just for the Ghost Edition. It's included in the Limited Edition and Digital Guardian Editions as well.

Comment: There does appear to be a lot of "Hats" in the game...

Comment: In the version I have (Taken King) the higher shells increase your light. Not just a hat (love that term, though).

Comment: Yeah, this answer is very out of date as it was before Taken king was released. I have not played Taken King so the answer will need to be updated by someone who knows how it works now.

Answer (score 2):

In my version of Destiny (Taken King, just got it for Christmas 2015), you can buy Ghost shells from the Speaker, if you are high enough level.

Also, it is not just a hat, a higher level Ghost shell adds (I believe) defense, so it increases your light.

Comment: Yes, but this was not true of the original game. You are correct, thanks for the updated answer.